# Bokeh and Apache2 Bad Websockets

Tags: python, apache, bokeh

I'm trying to run a Bokeh application on a server using Apache, however, it is unable to maintain any websockets because Apache keeps trying to redirect the web socket connection. I have been using the tutorial in Bokeh's documentation, with just a few modifications:

```
 <VirtualHost *:8080>
    # ... other stuff configuring my python virtual environment

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /sentiment_app/ws ws://127.0.0.1:5100/sentiment_app/ws
    ProxyPassReverse /sentiment_app/ws http://127.0.0.1:5100/sentiment_app/ws

    ProxyPass /sentiment_app http://127.0.0.1:5100/sentiment_app/
    ProxyPassReverse /sentiment_app http://127.0.0.1:5100/sentiment_app/

    <Directory />
        Require all granted
        Options -Indexes
    </Directory>

    # ... directory path configuration for static stuff, left out for brevity

</VirtualHost>
```

And the error that I get in the js console is:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://www.mypage.com:8080/sentiment_app/ws?bokeh-protocol-version=1.0&bokeh-session-id=hZGE5YRZWeIh6MhanZVIAyW4ioSOr9HP1geLWlE772Pe' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302

I have been playing around with the apache conf file for forever, have verified that mod_proxy_wstunnel and all the other things that need to run are up and configured, but still get the error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you navigating directly to the Apache 8080 URL? Or are you attempting to embed the app in another URL with `server_document` (or `autoload_server`)

Comment: Directly to the Apache 8080 URL. It also gives an error from Bokeh: Failed to connect to Bokeh server Error: Could not open websocket

Comment: Can you try starting the bokeh server with `--allow-websocket-origin <host>:8080` with whatever the host name you are navigating to?

Comment: I did end up doing that, and after a few hours it began working _on my computer_. However, now, when trying to access it from other computers the page gives the same errors.

Comment: The most frustrating problem is that nothing seems to give me adequate information about what is wrong.

Comment: Apache should have a log/error log somewhere, are there any messages in that? This seems like a problem at the Apache interface, Bokeh server would actually return a 502 if it was getting the request and denying it for some reason (ws origin not allowed, e.g)

Comment: No errors in the Apache log, and the access log only tells me that a connection is being made, nothing more.

Comment: Does the bokeh server log show any connection attempts? If there are no attempts then the problem is happening before every reaching the bokeh server.

Comment: had the same problem atm and stumbled over this issue:https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/8475